# Local push notifications only works in debug mode Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working in Xamarin Forms and have setup an Interface that I then call down to iOS and Android. On iOS I don't come across any issues but I am having some issues with Android.

Right now, things are working perfectly in debug mode, but once I test it in release mode, I do not get a notification sound, even though I have confirmed that the event is being called.

This is my android specific code:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Push_Droid))]
namespace Project.Droid.DI
{
public class Push_Droid : IPush
{
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Notification notification;

    internal static readonly string CHANNEL_ID = "my_notification_channel";
    NotificationChannel channel;
    private int IDCount = 0;

    public async Task HandleNewNotification(string User, string Text, string Image)
    {

        var context = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context;
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .SetContentTitle(User)
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.play)
                        .SetContentText(Text)
                        .SetAutoCancel(true)
                        .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            notificationManager = context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
            notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
        }
        else
        {
            var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .SetContentTitle(User)
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.play)
                        .SetContentText(Text)
                        .SetAutoCancel(true)
                        .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);


            notificationManager = context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

            channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "FCM Notifications", NotificationImportance.High);

            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
            notificationManager.Notify(IDCount, notificationBuilder.Build());
            IDCount++;
        }
    }
 }
```

Am i missing a permission or something of that sorts? I have not added anything in the manifest related to this feature - but i am eyeing the `AccessNotificaionPolicy` but when i read about it, it does not seem to be the solution to my problem.

Comment: I think there is no additional setting in release mode of local notification. Read the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications) and have a try with the [sample project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/localnotifications/) to see if it works under release mode.

Comment: I used their code, and now it works! Thx for the suggestion Jack

Comment: @DiddanDo could you point out the main difference between their code and yours and post that as an answer to this question? Would likely help everyone else stumbling over your question in the future.

Comment: In my case it doesn't work in debug mode!